# How to get the Local DB Path in titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

I want to get the local DB path by printing in the console. I tried the following code:

Ti.API.info(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory);

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation at https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Database-method-open

`var db = Ti.Database.open('mydb1Installed');`

**iOS:**

On simulator

`/Users/<user name>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<iOS version>/Applications/<apple app id>/Library/Private Documents/mydb1Installed.sql`

On device

`/Applications/<apple app id>/Library/Private Documents/mydb1Installed.sql`

**Android:**

`file:///data/data/appID/databases/mydb1Installed`